# Split variable and Store data into an array

Tags: php, split

I would like to store splitted data in an array like this:

```
$cp="my name is abcd";
$i=0;
$length=str_word_count($cp);
foreach ($cp as $c ) {
$array[i]=$c;
$i++; 
}
for($j=0;$j<$length;$j++){
echo $array[j]; 
}
```

It is not working ?

Comment: just `explode(' ', $cp)` and it will give you an array of words.

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  $cp="my name is abcd";
  $Words = explode(' ', $cp);

  foreach ($Words as $word) {
    echo "$word <br>";            
  }
?>
```

The $Words is the array that stores the values step by step

Answer (score 0):

Since OP has requested to grab each word one by one here is one method that uses strpos to find the position of the spaces and substring in a loop.
I use trim() to remove the space in the string since $pos is the position of the space.

```
$cp="my name is abcd";
$arr = array();
$pos=0;

While(strpos($cp, " ", $pos+1) != ""){// Keep going as long as there is spaces left in string
    $arr[] = trim(substr($cp, $pos, strpos($cp, " ", $pos+1)-$pos));
    $pos = strpos($cp, " ", $pos+1); //next space position
}

$arr[] = substr($cp, $pos+1); //catch the last one after loop +1 because POS is the space position.
Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/uJdIc

Answer (score 0):

I'm, not sure what's you need really, but may be this code can help you:

```
<?php

$cp="my name is abcd";

// words
$words=explode(' ',$cp);
print_r($words);

// letters
$letters=str_split($cp);
print_r($letters);
```

Here you can test them: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/728a283ba45118fef21cbb215a7424b293682018

Answer (score -1):

Just use `explode()`:

```
<?php
$cp="my name is abcd";
$arrayOfWords = explode(' ', $cp);
print_r($arrayOfWords);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => my [1] => name [2] => is [3] => abcd )
```